# chapterprecis overlaps with the chapter title

Tags: memoir

I am writing my thesis using memoir and chapterstyle with pedersen. However, the chapterprecis is overlapping with the chapter title. Here I attached a minimum code which could reproduce the problem. Hope someone could help me to solve this problem.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,arrows.meta}
\pagestyle{companion}

\definecolor{ared}{rgb}{.647,.129,.149}
\renewcommand\colorchapnum{\color{ared}}
\renewcommand\colorchaptitle{\color{ared}}
\chapterstyle{pedersen}

\begin{document}
\chapter{This is a test.}
\chapterprecis{
This is a test to show that the synopsis is overlapping with the chapter title.}

\lipsum[1-3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding

```
\setlength\prechapterprecisshift{0pt}
```

to the preamble. Chapter precis makes some assumptions about the chapter style that not always useful. In a non-article option doc, the default value here is `-2\baselineskip` corresponding to the normal `\afterchapskip` of `40pt`. But here `\afterchapskip` is only `10pt`.